# Inline styling failing to work with side menu

Tags: css

I'm not quite sure why I cannot seem to get this menu to go horizontal instead of vertical. I've followed a lot of community posts, using combinations of floats and inline-blocks etc and it seems I may be missing something.

Here is the code;

```
  <div class="sidebar-left">
      <div class="sidebar-links">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>1</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>2</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>3</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>4</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

---

```
.sidebar-left {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
}

.sidebar-left .sidebar-links {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.sidebar-links div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar-left .sidebar-links > a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #b3bcc5;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sidebar-links a i.fa {
  display: block;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/g8G4bE3MwWl68aHglF6U?p=preview

This has been very frustrating as something that I initially thought would be simple to do, has turned out to be a little tricky.

I'm hoping someone can point out where I have gone wrong!

Thanks

(Just to confirm : The aim is to make the menu horizontal, and not vertical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `display: inline-block` on your `a` elements instead of `display: block`. `display: block` causes the element to take up the entire width of the parent hence making them stack vertically. `display: inline-block` makes the elements only as wide as the content and stacks them horizontally.

http://plnkr.co/edit/se9mdVyTQ1qnJ1ZBrXYQ?p=preview

Comment: ah yes, I was trying to do it that way but I was forgetting to change the width so it still appeared vertical. Thanks for the answer!